# unable to get txtrecords from ServiceEvent in the function serviceAdded (From JmDNS)

Tags: android, jmdns

I 'm unable to get txtrecord  from `ServiceEvent` in the function `serviceAdded` (From JmDNS).

but I m able to get txtrecord from `ServiceEvent` in the function `serviceResolved`

The `serviceResolved` is executed at the start-up only 1 time and does not capte all services.

The `serviceAdded` is execute each time it capte a new service. but when trying to access to txtrecord, I found nothing in txtrecord I found only the service name.

are there a solution to get all txtRecord  each time I capte a new service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service info associated with the event of `serviceAdded` method does not include resolution information.
To get the full resolved information we need to call JmDNS.getServiceInfo(String, String, long)

```
public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
                   ServiceInfo inf = event.getDNS().getServiceInfo(event.getType(), event.getName());
               }
```

Reference: http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/apidocs/javax/jmdns/ServiceListener.html

Answer (score 1):

Also can be done by

```
 public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
                event.getDNS().requestServiceInfo(event.getType(), event.getName(), true);
 }
```

This will request for service resolution.